# I have a problem to display the legend in QGIS Web Client

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I have installed QGis Map Server and QGis Web Client on Centos 6.4 64-bit operating system, everything works fine except the legend box which is filled with garbage data instead of text (it seems that some fonts are missing), please have a look of the screenshot attached.

OS: 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Kernel: 
2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP

Software packages:
qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64; 
qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64;
mod_fcgid-2.3.7-1.el6.x86_64;
fcgi-2.4.0-10.el6.x86_64;
httpd-2.2.15-28.el6.centos.x86_64;
postgresql92-libs-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64;
postgresql92-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64;
postgresql92-server-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64;

[image]